# How can I restart phpmyadmin after big import

Tags: phpmyadmin

I've tried to import a `.sql` file via mysql, but it load since more than one hour. Is it possible to abort the import or restart phpmyadmin?

Greetings :)

Comment: how can you import by phpmyadmin or command prompt???

Comment: can data is imported or not?????

Comment: How big is your sql file? Does it finish loading? Are there any errors?